# Functor from $BG \to \text{Gpd}$ induces functors for each $g \in G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, functors, groupoids

I'm reading [Groupoids and Stuff](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/qg-spring2004/ByrneHons.pdf). Page 7.

> **Definition 1.3.1.** A **group action** of a a finite group $G$ on a groupoid $X$ is a functor $A : B G \to \text{Gpd}$ such that $A(I) = X$ where $I$ is the unique object of $BG$ (the category with one object and morphisms elements of $G$.)

This by definition means that each element $g \in G$ induces a functor $A(g) : X \to X$.

I'm having trouble seeing this.  Can you explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A functor takes a morphism $f : x \to y$ to a morphism $\mathcal{F}(f) : f(x) \to f(y)$.

In $BG$, the only object is $I$ and the only morphisms are the group elements $g : I \to I$. The functor $A$ takes one of these morphisms to a morphism $A(g) : A(I) \to A(I)$. Since $A(I) = X$ we have $A(g) : X \to X$.

Comment: Oh, I see it's a groupoid morphism or a functor that it gets taken to.